# Typagem dinâmica

Tags: javascript, react, typescript, front-end, next.js

Opa! Eu tentei fazer o seguinte:

```
type TabelaApontamentoProps = {
  arrayTitulo?: string[]
  data?: {

  }[]

  TemTipoLinha?: boolean
  NTipoLinha?: number
  CorTipoLinha?: string

  NColunaDestaque?: number
  NLinhaDestaque?: number
  CorDestaque?: string
} & (
    { TemTipoLinha: boolean; NTipoLinha: number; CorTipoLinha: string } |
    { TemTipoLinha?: boolean; NTipoLinha?: number; CorTipoLinha?: string }
  ) & (
    { NColunaDestaque: number; NLinhaDestaque: number; CorDestaque: string } |
    { NColunaDestaque?: number; NLinhaDestaque?: number; CorDestaque?: string }
  );
```

Mas quando eu passo TemTipoLinha={true} quando chamo meu componente, ele não pede para passar também o NTipoLinha e o CorTipoLinha e o mesmo vale para NColunaDestaque.Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Dei uma pesquisada e encontrei algo chamado 'Discriminated unions' na própria documentação do Typescript que vocês podem dar uma olhada em:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions

Meu código no fim ficou dessa forma:

```
type TabelaApontamentoProps = {
  arrayTitulo?: string[]
  data?: {

  }[]
  display?: () => void
}

interface Tipo {
  TemTipoLinha: boolean;
  NTipoLinha: number;
  CorTipoLinha: string;
}

interface Destaque {
  NColunaDestaque: number;
  NLinhaDestaque: number;
  CorDestaque: string;
}

type Resultado = TabelaApontamentoProps | Tipo | Destaque;
```